# Why resharper does not suggest to use linq when interating over a List?

Tags: c#, resharper

I am using Resharper 2018.1.3 (I updated to 2018.2.0 and I experienced the same issue) with Visual Studio 2017.

When I type this code:

```
var test = new List<string>();
var strings = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
foreach (var a in strings)
{
    test.Add(a);
}
```

Resharper suggests to convert it into LINQ-expression.

But if I use a `List`:

```
var test = new List<string>();
var strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
foreach (var a in strings)
{
    test.Add(a);
}
```

Resharper gives me no hint. Why?

Comment: Works for me using R# 2016. Results in `test = strings.ToList();`

Comment: @HimBromBeere I've included the version I use (2018.1.3)

Comment: What did JetBrains say when you asked them?

Comment: @mjwills You're right, I asked there https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000621419-Why-resharper-does-not-suggest-to-use-linq-when-interating-over-a-List-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in this particular  case the transformation to LINQ looks safe, in general it can have unexpected side effects. `System.Collections.Generic.List` has a special implementation of `GetEnumerator` method which returns a struct. LINQ methods works with `IEnumerable` where `GetEnumerator` methods return instance of interface `IEnumerator`. So, converting `foreach` to LINQ can cause undesired boxing.

In some cases `GetEnumerator` method used by `foreach` and implementation of `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` can return completely different `Enumerator`s like we have in `IDictionary` where `GetEnumerator` enumerates over `DictionaryEntry`s while implementation of `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` iterates over objects which are actually instances of `KeyValuePair` in case of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`.

Comment: Oh, this is very interesting! Do you know if there is an option to enable this hint in all cases? Generally, I do not care about those negligible performance issues, but I do care about readability.

Comment: No, there is no option to enable this hint in all cases